# 'p-progressSpinner' is not a known element

Tags: angular, spinner, primeng, primeng-spinner

the version pf primeng that i use is the latest one : 13.4.0
In the app module, i've import the Spinner module :

```
import { ProgressSpinnerModule } from 'primeng/progressspinner';
```

also :

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
```

In the html, i just add the spinner tag in my-component:

```
<p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>

<div *ngIf="contrats.length===0">
    <!-- Pas de contrats -->
    
    <p>Aucun contrat trouvé</p>
</div>

<div *ngIf="contrats.length!==0">
<div>
    <!-- Header Search -->
    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Nom et Prenom" [(ngModel)]="nomComplet">
    <button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-search" styleClass="p-button-warn" (click)="recherche()"></button>
    <label>Criteres de recherche</label>
</div>
```

And my-component ts file :

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicDialogConfig, DynamicDialogRef } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { Adherent } from 'src/app/espace-client/collectivites/model/adherent.model';
import { Contrat } from 'src/app/espace-client//model/contrat.model';
import { ContratService, AdherentService } from 'business-client';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { LoadingService } from 'src/app/services/loading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
```

and it's not recognized !!! why ?
it show this error :
'p-progressSpinner' is not a known element

Comment: In what component you are using p-progressSpinner? and that component is still part of app module or not?

Comment: Can you update your question to include your code, i.e. app.module.ts, app.component.html, app.component.ts, package.json would help to see your NPM dependencies.

Comment: Yes, the component is part of app module, i've checked it (adding another module)

Comment: @RobinWebb i've update the post, the app.module is very long and also the html and the ts file, i just add the essantial part

In my-component ts file, there is no update related to spinner

Comment: Which module is your my-component in? Maybe you need to add import { ProgressSpinnerModule } from 'primeng/progressspinner'; to this module if it's not app modeul?

Comment: @RobinWebb i've one module in my app

Comment: Not sure without seeing code. One thought..how are you running your project "ng serve"? Or are you npm run watch? Perhaps try CTRL-C and rebuild? I just tried the component on a fresh Angular install and work OK with simple configuration.